# Babel 7 (webpack) transpile to most backwards compatible code

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to configure webpack/babel 7 to transpile to the most backwards compatible code possible. But I still see things like `includes` and `find` in my code.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"]
  ],
}
```

How can I tell babel to do the most it can?

Comment: Babel will compile to whichever ES version IE7 supports, but any missing functionality will need to be provided by polyfills.

Comment: Ok the example maybe misleading, I just want to have the most backwards compatible code. I will remove the ie part from the example. What polyfills do I need?

Comment: @select babel has a [suite of polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) from the core js folks. That will get you back to IE 6 IIRC. That's the easy part. The *hard* part is optimizing the bundle based on what the client actually needs/application actually uses. But a better answer to your question is that you should generally prefer *syntax* (which babel will compile for you) over *methods/functions* (which it doesn't). For example: `const bar = {...foo}` vs `const bar = Object.assign({}, foo);`

Answer (score 0):

From https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env, we can use a browser list string or target browsers individually (see below for example).

```
 {
     "presets": [
         ["@babel/preset-env", {
             "targets" : ">0.001%" 
         } ] 
      ]
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Will this make e.g. `Promise` or `Object.assign` work on IE? No.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but the problems I showed still exist

Comment: that's because IE 6 and 7 have a 0.01% market share each (less than the 0.25% my query specified), the query in my answer is just an example of a browserlist query -  you need to make the browserlist query for the browsers you want to support, I'll edit my answer to use a query that should work in your situation.